# Transactional Emails not Sending

Tags: magento

We are running a magento store (1.6.0) on a linux server with email for the domain on a Microsoft Exchange Server.  No transactional emails are getting to customers with the email address associated with the same domain, but are getting to accounts outside of the domain (hotmail and gmail, etc).

Any solutions for this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have Magento configured to use the Exchange Server as the MTA or are you using sendmail?  (Configuration > System > SMTP Settings).  There's a chance that Exchange Server has some spam setting that is blocking the inbound mail.

Comment: We have nothing set up.  Not sure what to put there.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off mail services on the Linux server.  Let's say your domain is "domain.com" and your Exchange Server is also "domain.com".  When the Linux server tries to send to "info@domain.com" the Linux server thinks that the mail should be delivered to itself instead of your Exchange Server.  When you turn off mail service on the Linux Server then it will no longer try to deliver to itself.

Comment: Yes, the mail is turned off on the subdomain.